# Ubuntu snappy docker ps not working

Tags: ubuntu-core, docker

When a run:

```
sudo docker ps
```

in ubuntu snappy i get this error:

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Do you know any solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file called `cloud.cfg` with the exact lines of text you see below:

```
#cloud-config
    snappy:
        ssh_enabled: True
```

save in `/home/user/google-cloud` folder

and run: `sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/google-ecdsa ubuntu@ <external IP>`

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a better solution to the problem, which is to run the command:

```
sudo aa-clickhook -f
```

My old solution is below:

I had the same issue. The only thing I found which made it possible to use docker again on snappy core, was to remove and reinstall the docker framework using the commands:

```
sudo snappy remove docker
```

followed by

```
sudo snappy install docker
```

At that point I was able to run docker commands without incident. I found that my docker images were still available to me, and the ones started with the flag `--restart always` automatically restarted when the docker framework was reinstalled.

Comment: I traced this issue to an update of the ubuntu-core which was automatically applied by the system-image client. After the reboot, the new system image was applied, and the docker images started and ran fine, however apparmor seemed to be preventing me from using the unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: I found a better solution, which is to regenerate the security policies using the command:

    sudo aa-clickhook -f